# NodeJS - Faça um algoritmo que leia a altura e a matricula de dez alunos. Mostre a matricula do aluno mais alto e do aluno mais baixo

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tudo que consigo é mostrar a altura do menor para o maior, porém quero mostrar à quais matrículas as alturas pertencem (matrícula do menor aluno, matrícula do maior aluno, etc)

````
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

nome = [];
height = [];
mat = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    nome[i] = readlineSync.question('Nome do aluno: ')
    height[i] = parseFloat(readlineSync.question('Altura do aluno: '));
    mat[i] = parseFloat(readlineSync.question('Matrícula: '));
    console.log('\n');

};

for (let x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
    console.log(`[NOME] -> ${nome[x]} -> [ALTURA] -> ${height[x]} -> [MATRÍCULA] -> ${mat[x]}`);
};

console.log(`\n[${height.sort()}] -> Do mais alto para o mais baixo`);
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, como você quer armazenar múltiplas informações de **uma mesma entidade** (no caso, um aluno), vale mais a pena você criar um único *array* de [objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos) ao invés de três *arrays*, um para cada informação.

Então, você terá algo assim:

```js
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

const alunos = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    // Criamos um novo objeto para o aluno.
    const aluno = {
      nome: readlineSync.question('Nome do aluno: ')
      height: parseFloat(readlineSync.question('Altura do aluno: '));
      mat: parseFloat(readlineSync.question('Matrícula: '));
    };

    // Inserimos o aluno no array de alunos:
    alunos.push(aluno);

    console.log('\n');
};
```

Após isso, para determinar os objetos dos alunos com menor e maior altura, uma das formas é utilizar um laço `for` em conjunto com duas "variáveis externas", para armazenar os objetos do menor e maior alunos. Algo assim:

```js
const alunos = [
  { nome: 'A', height: 4, mat: 'AAA' },
  { nome: 'B', height: 3, mat: 'BBB' },
  { nome: 'C', height: 5, mat: 'CCC' },
  { nome: 'D', height: 1, mat: 'DDD' },
  { nome: 'E', height: 2, mat: 'EEE' },
];

let maiorAluno = null;
let menorAluno = null;

for (const aluno of alunos) {
  // Caso nenhum aluno ainda tenha sido classificado como maior ou menor:
  if (!maiorAluno || !menorAluno) {
    if (!maiorAluno) maiorAluno = aluno;
    if (!menorAluno) menorAluno = aluno;
    
    continue;
  }
  
  if (aluno.height > maiorAluno.height) {
    maiorAluno = aluno;
  }
  
  if (aluno.height < menorAluno.height) {
    menorAluno = aluno;
  }
}

console.log('Maior aluno:', maiorAluno);
console.log('Menor aluno:', menorAluno);
```

Uma outra opção é utilizar o `sort`, criando uma função de comparação baseada na propriedade `height` de cada objeto. Em seguida, capturar o primeiro e último elementos. Assim:

```js
const alunos = [
  { nome: 'A', height: 4, mat: 'AAA' },
  { nome: 'B', height: 3, mat: 'BBB' },
  { nome: 'C', height: 5, mat: 'CCC' },
  { nome: 'D', height: 1, mat: 'DDD' },
  { nome: 'E', height: 2, mat: 'EEE' },
];

const alunosOrdenadosPorAltura = alunos.sort((a, b) =>
  a.height - b.height // Irá ordenar do menor para o maior.
);

const maiorAluno = alunosOrdenadosPorAltura[0];
const menorAluno = alunosOrdenadosPorAltura[alunosOrdenadosPorAltura.length - 1];

console.log('Maior aluno:', maiorAluno);
console.log('Menor aluno:', menorAluno);
```